# Rendering partial collection with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got my javascript working I think but now its not loading the content. Just a blank space. I currently have this in my create.js.erb

```
$('#pit_form').remove(); //remove form
$('#new_link').show();  //show new link again
$('#pit_index').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'pits/pit', :collection => @pits) %>")
```

I added @pits in my create action in pits_controller as well.

Controller

```
class PitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

def new
  @pit = Pit.new
end

def index
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pits = Pit.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').group_by { |pit| pit.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
end




def create
    @pit = current_user.pits.create(pit_params)
    @pits = Pit.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').group_by { |pit| pit.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }  
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @pit}
        format.js
  end
end



def show
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
end

def update
   @pit = Pit.find(pit_params[:id])
     if @pit.update_attributes(pit_params)
       redirect_to @pit
     end
end

def destroy
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
  @pit.destroy
end


def upvote
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @pit.upvote_from current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def downvote
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @pit.downvote_from current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end


private

def correct_user
    @pit = current_user.pits.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_path if @pit.nil?
  end

def pit_params
    params.require(:pit).permit(:topic, :summary, :image, :video_url, :author, :user_id)
end

end
```

My logs say its loading the content but nothing but a big blank space shows up.

Logs

```
Started POST "/pits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-03 13:43:20 -0500
Processing by PitsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "pit"=>{"topic"=>"test", "author"=>"test", "summary"=>"test", "video_url"=>""}, "commit"=>"Start Pit"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "pits" ("author", "created_at", "summary", "topic", "updated_at", "user_id", "video_url") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["author", "test"], ["created_at", "2014-09-03 18:43:20.845193"], ["summary", "test"], ["topic", "test"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-03 18:43:20.845193"], ["user_id", 1], ["video_url", ""]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
  Pit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "pits".* FROM "pits"   ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  Rendered pits/_pit.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered pits/create.js.erb (2.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 5.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

Based on my searches it would seem that added @pits to the create action would solve it per other answers but not with mine. Would love some help.

My index.html.erb

```
<div class = "container list-pits", id = "pit_index"> 
  <%= link_to "Add New Pit", new_pit_path, id: "new_link", remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <% @pit.each do |pit| %>

  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "well"> 
       <h3 id="pit-title"><%= link_to pit.topic, pit_path(pit) %></h3>
       <p>by <%= link_to pit.author, '#' %></p>
          <br>
            <p><%= pit.summary %></p>
            <p>Replies (<%= pit.comments.count %>)</p>
          <br>

            <p>Pit Created by: <%= link_to pit.user.name, pit.user %> on <%= pit.created_at %></p>

            <%= link_to "View Pit", pit_path(pit), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <%= link_to "Delete Pit", pit_path(pit), remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
      </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

_pit.html.erb

<

```
div class = "container list-pits", id = "pit_index"> 
  <%= link_to "Add New Pit", new_pit_path, id: "new_link", remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <% @pit.each do |pit| %>

  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "well"> 
       <h3 id="pit-title"><%= link_to pit.topic, pit_path(pit) %></h3>
       <p>by <%= link_to pit.author, '#' %></p>
          <br>
            <p><%= pit.summary %></p>
            <p>Replies (<%= pit.comments.count %>)</p>
          <br>

            <p>Pit Created by: <%= link_to pit.user.name, pit.user %> on <%= pit.created_at %></p>

            <%= link_to "View Pit", pit_path(pit), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <%= link_to "Delete Pit", pit_path(pit), remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
      </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>


 </div>
```

I threw the same thing above in my _pit partial per a few suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: check if u have js error in your browser console, also try to throw a `console.log` to see if that js runs or not

Comment: I'd like to see your `views/pits/_pit.html.erb` file, please

Comment: I'll try to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Collection**

To give you some further scope, the `collection` argument of the `partial` helper *basically* replaces the `.each` aspect of your `partial`. An important point is that you need to note the local object you wish to call [with the `as:` argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables):

> To use a custom local variable name within the partial, specify the
>   :as option in the call to the partial:
>
> `<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products, as: :item %>`
>
> With this change, you can access an instance of the @products
>   collection as the item local variable within the partial.

This means if you're rendering a partial with `collection`, you need to ensure it has the adjacent `as:` method to give you the correct local variable name. Further, as `Ruby Racer` outlined in his answer, you should only be using the `collection` argument for *collections* of data:

```
#app/views/pits/create.js.erb
$('#pit_index').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'pits/pit', collection: @pits, as: :pit) %>")
```

This will load the `pit` partial as if you had called `@pits.each do |pit|`, which means you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/views/pits/_pit.html.erb
<div class = "container list-pits", id = "pit_index">     
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "well"> 
       <h3 id="pit-title"><%= link_to pit.topic, pit_path(pit) %></h3>
       <p>by <%= link_to pit.author, '#' %></p>
          <br>
            <p><%= pit.summary %></p>
            <p>Replies (<%= pit.comments.count %>)</p>
          <br>

            <p>Pit Created by: <%= link_to pit.user.name, pit.user %> on <%= pit.created_at %></p>

            <%= link_to "View Pit", pit_path(pit), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <%= link_to "Delete Pit", pit_path(pit), remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Fix**

You have several issues (which I've resolved above), namely that you're using `@pit` inside your partial.

`@pit` is an *instance* variable, meaning that it can only be set in the controller. If you're using partials, you'll be calling *local* variables, which are distinctively different in scope than `@instance` vars.

Looking at your logs, it seems that your `partial` is being called, but your use of `@pit.each` will likely just be causing the blank space. My recommendation resolves this

Comment: Thanks Rich. I was sort of wondering if just removing the @ pits.each do |pit| from the partial was a part of the solution. Implementing it however, has been obviously difficult for me. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the "blank" spot by changing some of the markup in my _form. However, it is still not inserting the pit_index portion into the page.

Comment: So I finally got it to work using your example when I changed my controller. I think something was wrong with pagination so I just included @pits = Pit.order('created_ASC') in my create and index action. Thanks to both of you for time and efforts. I do really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

`render :partial => 'pits/pit', :collection => @pits`

If you were familiar with the documentation, you should know that this means that you will be using a partial which will render ONE object, not a collection, for each object in the collection.

A generic (not from your code) partial would be:

_pit.html.erb:

```
name: <%= pit.name %>
surname: <%= pit.surname %>
<%# etcetera %>
```

Now, if you want to use a partial containing a collection, then you should change your partial and the call to it.

Change the partial:
change each `@pits` (or `@pit`, as you have pasted it) to `pits`

Change the way you call it (send a local variable):
`render :partial => 'pits/pit', locals: {pits: @pits}`

And that should do the trick.

UPDATE:

Change this:

```
<% @pit.each do |pit| %>
```

to this:

```
<% pits.each do |pit| %>
```

And this:

```
$('#pit_index').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'pits/pit', :collection => @pits) %>")
```

To this:

```
$('#pit_index').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'pits/pit', locals: {pits: @pits}) %>")
```

**UPDATE**
Your @pits is a hash of arrays (group_by{} has been used). So, you should probably change your partial like this:

```
<% pits.each do |current_value, pitarrray| %>
    <%# maybe do some grouping actions here %>
    <% pitarray.each do |pit| %>
```

Don't forget, there will be two `<% end %>` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. This is my first time trying to use AJAX in an app.

Comment: Change this <% @ pit.each do |pit| %> to this <% @ pit.each do |pits| %>? Or change something like <%= pit.name %> to this <%= pits.name %>? Sorry, I'm still trying to get all the syntax down here. I get the concept but implementing it correctly is my weak point here I think.

Comment: Racer, you misunderstand the `collection` value in `partial` renders - I'll write an answer to explain

Comment: Actually, I tried giving the answer with the least degree of intervention. Not rewrite a large portion of his code.

Comment: You both have been very helpful. I appreciate your patience with Newbies like myself. I'm sure it often feels like a broken record at times:) I've never used collections before and didn't even know about it until I ran into this issue, so its been a good learning process. I'll reformat somethings here and let you know how it pans out. Thanks.

Comment: So I tried both answers here. Rich's answer still gave me the blank chunk at the top but my logs say everything was loaded and rendered. This makes me wonder if there is possibly something wrong with my markup? Not sure.

Racer's answer gave me undefined method `topic' for #<Array:0x000001019aff18>): contained here -> <h3 id="pit-title"><%= link_to pit.topic, pit_path(pit) %></h3>

I'm perplexed here as to why it allows me to as much in the index file but not in my partial when using  <%= j (render :partial => 'pits/pit', locals: {pits: @pits}) %>

Comment: I must note that if I refresh the page per Rich's answer it loads the page correctly with the correct markup it just doesn't insert it in unless I refresh. It gives me the blank portion

Comment: Or maybe an issue with the link_to?

Comment: `pit` should be an instance not an array. Are you doing `<% pits.each do |pit| %>`?

Comment: Yes. I just checked. Same error as above. Also, when I inspect element under console I get this error - POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/pits 500 (Internal Server Error) application.js:9632send application.js:9632jQuery.extend.ajax application.js:9177$.rails.rails.ajax application.js:10393$.rails.rails.handleRemote application.js:10473(anonymous function) application.js:10720jQuery.event.dispatch application.js:4642elemData.handle

Comment: Server log would be more helpful

Comment: I also note you have a before_action filter for "current_user", but I don't see it in your private section, in your controller.

Comment: I'm using Devise. I could be wrong but I thought it was already defined? Correct me if I'm wrong. My server logs are the same as above - ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `topic' for #<Array:0x000001082a5fb8>):

Comment: I've got it. Each element in your collection is an array (since you use `group_by{}`. So, use my updated version.